# Special characters in UTF-8 stored as diamond with question mark in MYSQL using magento

Tags: php, mysql, magento, encoding, utf-8

I am reading a csv encoded in UTF-8 with some special characters such as `ò` . I use htmlentities to store the UTF-8 characters to their HTML equivalent. But such special characters get stored as diamond with question mark in MYSQL db.

My code is :-

```
$fileName = $_FILES['csv_file']['tmp_name'];
ini_set('auto_detect_line_endings', 1);
$fp = fopen($fileName, 'r');

$resource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');
$writeAdapter = $resource->getConnection('core_write');
$optionsNumber = 4;

$line = true;
while ($line !== false){
    $names      = array();
    $namesIndex = 0;
    while (($line = fgetcsv($fp, self::MAX_LINE, ',', '"')) !== false) {

        $empty_row = false;
        for ($i = 0; $i < $optionsNumber+1; $i++) {
            $line[$i] = trim($line[$i], "\r\n\t' ".'"');
            $line[$i] = htmlentities($line[$i], ENT_SUBSTITUTE, "UTF-8");

            $sql2 = "insert ignore into `custom_table` ". "(parent_id, options_id, value, p_id) values ". "(:parent_id, :options_id, :value,:p_id)";

            $binds = array(
                'parent_id'      => 0,  
                'options_id'     => 1,
                'value'          => $line[$i],
                'p_id'           => 1,
            );
            $writeAdapter->query($sql2,$binds);
        }       
    }   
}
```

Now the problem is the value `Motò 6.5` is stored as `Mot� 6.5`

Someone please point out what is the mistake. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please use below line

```
$line[$i] = utf8_encode($line[$i]);
```

instead of

```
$line[$i] = htmlentities($line[$i], ENT_SUBSTITUTE, "UTF-8");
```

Comment: this won't help, it will result in double utf8 encoded data as his data already is utf8

Comment: maybe, but you don't know his php-file enconding and database character set and collations...

Comment: Yes this works, but unfortunately it adds some illegal characters in the beginning of my first value like `ï»¿`. why so ?

Comment: lol, so you say it works but it does not work as well? we can not tell unless you provide info on character sets, encoding and collation of all involved points such as database, db-connection, source-files and data-files.

Comment: Table schema must be utf8_general_ci

Comment: the source csv file in utf-8 encoded, the database has utf8_general_ci collation, the db-connection is default magento write connection

Comment: Remove this line and than try 
$line[$i] = trim($line[$i], "\r\n\t' ".'"');

and its better to use another variable instead of updating current
$value = utf8_encode($line[$i]);

Comment: i will resolve that. Howerver, the special characters are stored perfectly. Thanks a ton

Comment: `ï»¿` smells like Mojibake for `ZERO WIDTH NO-BREAK SPACE`; do you think that is what you wanted there?

Answer (score 1):

it can have many origins. for example a problem resulting from the encoding of your php-file. to avoid such problems you can follow the following rules:

1. have all php-files encoded utf8 without bom
2. make the database/tables/fields use character-set utf8 and collation `utf8_general_ci`
3. right after connecting to your mysql database execute the following query: `"SET NAMES UTF8;"`
4. have all data loaded by php in utf8

you will never ever have any encoding issues nomore ;)

Comment: One more:  In the HTML output, have `<meta charset=UTF-8>`.

Comment: (The collation is not relevant to this discussion.)